# How to make subrule/regex case-insensitive when used in match?

Tags: regex, match, raku, case-insensitive

I am trying to match any keywords in a group. Keywords are in array @b. I am unable to make case-insensitive matches. I have done some testing, and the following script is an example:

```
> my $line = "this is a test line";
this is a test line

> my @b = < tes lin > ; 
[tes lin]

> my regex a { || @b };
regex a { || @b }

> say $line ~~ m:i/ <a> /    # matching the first as expected
｢tes｣
 a => ｢tes｣

> say $line ~~ m:i:g/ <a> /  # matching both as expected
(｢tes｣
 a => ｢tes｣ ｢lin｣
 a => ｢lin｣)

> my @b = < tes LIN > ; 
[tes LIN]
> my regex a { || @b };
regex a { || @b }
> say $line ~~ m:i:g/ <a> /   # should match both "tes" and "LIN" but skips "LIN"
(｢tes｣
 a => ｢tes｣)

> my @b = < TES lin >
[TES lin]
> my regex a { || @b }
regex a { || @b }
> say $line ~~ m:i:g/ <a> /   # expect to match both but skips "TES"
(｢lin｣
 a => ｢lin｣)
```

Also, mapping to all lower cases does not work:

```
> my @b = < TES lin >.lc
[tes lin]
> my regex a { || @b }
regex a { || @b }
> say $line ~~ m:i:g/ <a> /
()
```

My question is, how should case-insensitivity be handled when a regex/subrule is actually called?

I tried to put :i adverb inside regex a but the resulting matches are futile:

```
> my regex a { :i || @b }
regex a { :i || @b }
> say $line ~~ m:i:g/ <a> /
(｢｣
 a => ｢｣ ｢｣
```

and then 19 lines of "a => ｢｣ ｢｣"

```
 a => ｢｣)
```

Comment: `<FOO bar>.lc` turns into the single string `'foo bar'`, not a list of two strings `(foo bar)` so `<TES lin>.lc` turns into an array `[tes lin]` that contains *one* element, the string `'tes lin'`, a 7 character long string including a space, not two elements that are each three character long strings.

Comment: Thank you very much  raiph for you help again !!! <>.lc was my fault for mistaking something so obvious :-( Thank you !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with:

```perl6
my regex a { || @b }
say $line ~~ m:i/ <a> /
```

Is that `a` is the regex in charge of matching the values in `@b`, and it isn't compiled with `:i`.
In Perl6 regexes are code, you can't change how a regex works from a distance like that.

Then there is another problem with:

```perl6
my regex a { :i || @b }
```

It is really compiled as:

```perl6
my regex a {
     [ :i    ]
  ||
     [    @b ]
}
```

That is match `ignorecase[nothing]` and if that fails (it won't fail) match one of the values in `@b`.

The only reason to use `|| @…` is so that it matches the values in `@…` in the order they are defined.

```perl6
> my @c = < abc abcd foo >;

> say 'abcd' ~~ / || @c /
｢abc｣
```

I think that in most cases it would actually work better to just let it be the default `|` semantics.

```perl6
> my @c = < abc abcd foo >;

> say 'abcd' ~~ / |  @c /
｢abcd｣
> say 'abcd' ~~ /    @c /
｢abcd｣
```

So then this would work the way you want it to:

```perl6
my regex a { :i @b }
```

---

That is `<a>|<b>` will match whichever has the longest starting expression. While `<a>||<b>` will try `<a>` first, and if that fails it will try `<b>`.

---

If you really want `||` semantics, any of these would work:

```perl6
my regex a {     ||  :i @b  }
my regex a { :i [||     @b] }
```

The following doesn't have `||` semantics.
In fact the `||` doesn't do anything.

```perl6
my regex a {     || [:i @b] }
```

It is the same as these:

```perl6
my regex a {     |   :i @b  }
my regex a {         :i @b  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Brad Gilbert !!! You really clarified many concepts not explicitly stated in the Perl6 docs site. I will revise my coding. Thanks !!!